# Android:video as splash screen

Tags: android-video-player

I want to play the video as splash screen.I have implement the play video but it show the default control like play,pause and seek etc.I want to remove the 
   so that the after video finish I need to call the new activity.

```
 MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    video.setMediaController(mc);
    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    video.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ontouch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
        }) ;
```

and the main.xml

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer was too simple
         remove the line

```
 video.setMediaController(mc);
```

because i did not want to use the control.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Disable the touchable property in the layout.xml file:

```
<VideoView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/videoView1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:clickable="false"/>
```

Hope that helps you

Now there is a Method called

```
setMediaController(MediaController mCtrl)
```

http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setMediaController%28android.widget.MediaController%29

You can call this method and pass the argument as MediaController.hide()

Here is a Sample Code:

```
MediaController controller=MediaController(Context);
controller.hide();
VideoView videoView= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
videoView.setMediaController(controller);
//try passing null here as well
```

Comment: i have done it but still show me the media controller in start