# Android, how can I remove controls of VideoView?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

In my project I have a Video View that I put it in splash screen. Everything is OK and I can see it in splash screen but the problem is when it shows, control bar (back, next, time length) will show as well that I want see it. How can I disable it?

In the sample code (that I got my idea), it had

> mVideoView.requestFocus();

that I removed it but still I think it has focus and because of this it shows control bar. Am I right? How can I prevent and don't let to show?

update:
This is my code:

```
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.splash_video);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.infindo.motogp/raw/sp"));
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android:video as splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473553/androidvideo-as-splash-screen)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473553/androidvideo-as-splash-screen)

Just remove setMediaController. If you don't have it, paste your code so we can see what could be the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to remove `videoView.setMediaController();`

Comment: Thanks Deni for your confirmation. It would be better if you can put it as comment under approved answer instead. Thanks.

Comment: I can't comment because my reputation still not enought

Answer (score 1):

Try to hide it by  using this

```
videoView=findViewById(R.id.video_id);

videoView.setOnTouchListener();
```